# How would I get the output of a function from a different running python script?

Tags: python, flask, message-queue, discord.py

I currently am running two separate python scripts, one for a Flask webapp and the other for a discord.py bot. Upon receiving an incoming request on the flask webapp, I would like to call a function in the discord.py script and return the its output to the view.

Currently both scripts are blocking so I am interested in using a redis messaging queue to pass requests between each other (something like the [kombu](https://github.com/celery/kombu) package).

webapp.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    user = get_user(123456789) # get_user function from bot.py
    return "Hello, {0}".format(user.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

bot.py:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

async def get_user(user_id):
    user = await client.get_user_info(user_id)
    return user

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.run("bot token")
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this task or if Kombu is really the way to go. How would I implement to my flask webapp so that I can call functions within my discord.py bot?

Comment: It doesn't really look like you want to be using a discord bot at all, you just want to interact with the API to retrieve information.  You might want to dig into the internals of how the `get_user_info` coroutine works, and eschew the bot entirely in favor of making your own requests to the API.

Comment: I'm just using the get_user_info function here as a small example. I intend to share some functions from my bot.py script to the flask script that involves a bit more work than to fetch an API and return the result. @Patrick Haugh

Comment: I think a solution in which you completely divorce the discord bot from the webserver is probably best.  Have the two interact over some messaging protocol (web requests, socket IO, queues, etc.).  You should be able to create new events listeners that you can register with your `discord.py` bot, to get functionality similar to things like `on_message`.

Comment: Currently the two scripts are ran independent of each other. I am looking into libraries such as kombu and rq to implement a redis queue. But I am clueless on how one would go about implementing it. Is there any examples that would implement a messaging queue to call a function in the second script that would return it's result to the first one? @PatrickHaugh

Answer (score -2):

Use import function from other file

from bot import get_user

and make sure, you have both file in same directory.